# How to set an attribute conditionally in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `span` element displaying some value. If the value isn't 0, I want to apply some `styleClass` to the element:

```
<span styleClass="alert-error">{{value}}</span>
```

Otherwise, if the value is 0, I don't want to apply the `styleClass`. An empty `styleClass` attribute would be acceptable:

```
<span styleClass="">{{value}}</span>
```

How can I do this with AngularJS?

Comment: I'm curious, if you are trying to apply an attribute named `styleClass` or you are trying to apply the `class` attribute.

Comment: `styleClass` actually comes from jsf, which I don't need anymore now that I'm going for AngularJS. So it's in fact the `class` attribute I want to apply.

Comment: yup! see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (just use the ternary operator):

```
<span styleClass="{{value == 0 ? '' : 'alert-error'}}">{{value}}</span>
```

**Edit:**

For class attribute just to the same like others have already mentioned:

```
<span class="{{value == 0 ? '' : 'alert-error'}}">{{value}}</span>
```

Also, you can use `ng-class`:

```
<span ng-class="{'alert-error': (value != 0)}">{{value}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

@shashank solution is good.

I always prefer to have logic part in controller or service. My solution would be like

```
$scope.getStyleCSS = function () {
    if ($scope.getValue() !== 0) {
        return 'alert-error';
    }
    return '';
}

$scope.getValue = function () {
    return $scope.value;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span styleClass="getStyleCSS()" ng-bind="getValue()"></span>
```

> It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} if a template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Make use of [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<span ng-class="{{value == 0 ? '' : 'alert-error'}}">{{value}}</span>
```

Comment: It seems like there is something missing. This is the resulting code: `<span class="ng-binding" ng-class="alert-error">5</span>`. And the style is NOT applied.